# xml load error DTD must be defined before the document root element

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to load an xml file but getting the following error.

> DTD must be defined before the document root element.

the xml file is generated by others, i found that there are html elements in the xml file. How do i delete the html in the xml file using c#?

Updated:

Hi, I sorry that i cannot show to full xml file due to company p&c. But below are the html part that i mention.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<loanreservation>
<loanid></loanid>
<status>WEB_REQUEST</status>
<requesterid>abc</requesterid>
<borrowerid>abc</borrowerid>
<borrowerorgid>abc</borrowerorgid>
<borrowerlocid>abcborrowerlocid>
<authcontactid></authcontactid>
<escalationcontactid></escalationcontactid>
<specialinstructions>specialinstructions>
<internalnotes></internalnotes>
<usestartdate>2018-09-03</usestartdate>
<useenddate>2018-09-17</useenddate>
<mustshipdate>2018-08-30</mustshipdate>
<mustreceivedate>2018-10-01</mustreceivedate>
<checkoutdate></checkoutdate>
<checkindate></checkindate>
<intendeduse></intendeduse>
<reason></reason>
<shiptolocid>abc</shiptolocid>
<shipaddress1></shipaddress1>
<shipaddress2></shipaddress2>
<shipaddress3></shipaddress3>
<shipaddress4></shipaddress4>
<shippostalcode></shippostalcode>
<shipcity></shipcity>
<shipstate></shipstate>
<shipprovince></shipprovince>
<shipcountry></shipcountry>
<shiptocontactid></shiptocontactid>
<shiptocontactphone></shiptocontactphone>
<shiptocontactfax></shiptocontactfax>
<shiptocontactemail></shiptocontactemail>
<returnpickuplocid></returnpickuplocid>
<returnpickupcontactid></returnpickupcontactid>
<returnpickupcontactphone></returnpickupcontactphone>
<returnpickupcontactfx></returnpickupcontactfx>
<returnpickupcontactemail></returnpickupcontactemail>
<returnpickuplocation></returnpickuplocation>
<returnpickupaddress1></returnpickupaddress1>
<returnpickupaddress2></returnpickupaddress2>
<returnpickupaddress3></returnpickupaddress3>
<returnpickupaddress4></returnpickupaddress4>
<returnpickuppostalcode></returnpickuppostalcode>
<returnpickupcity></returnpickupcity>
<returnpickupstate></returnpickupstate>
<returnpickupprovince></returnpickupprovince>
<returnpickupcountry></returnpickupcountry>
<loanorgpoolid></loanorgpoolid>
<contactloginid></contactloginid>
<lastupdate></lastupdate>
<createdate></createdate>
<approvalcontactid></approvalcontactid>
<approveddate></approveddate>
<shippingwaybill></shippingwaybill>
<shippingcarrier></shippingcarrier>
<shippingnoofboxes></shippingnoofboxes>
<shippingtotalweight></shippingtotalweight>
<returnwaybill></returnwaybill>
<returncarrier></returncarrier>
<returnnoofboxes></returnnoofboxes>
<returntotalweight></returntotalweight>
<reservationitems>
<item>
<loanid></loanid>
<equipno></equipno>
<assetno></assetno>
<manufacturer></manufacturer>
<manufmodelno></manufmodelno>
<serialno></serialno>
<options></options>
<chassisno></chassisno>
<slotno></slotno>
<configid></configid>
</item>
</reservationitems>
<accessories>
<item></item>
</accessories>
</loanreservation>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/base-font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tabs.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/webforms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/im.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ice_infoline.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/internal_portal.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/dhtml-base.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../public/locale-script.aspx"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/template.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/dhtml-menus.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../scripts/report-definition.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../webfx/scripts/webforms-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../webfx/scripts/webforms.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width:60px; height: 100%; background-color: #555555;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:0px; height: 100%">
    <div style="display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-row; width=100%">
    <div style="border-bottom:6px #e90029 solid; margin-bottom: 10px;  ">
    <div class="bodycontainer">
    <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.keysight.com"><img src="../acom-lf/keysight-logo.png"></a>
    <span style="display: inline-block; color: #555555; font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 20px; margin-left: 30px" >Infoline</span>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; width=100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="bodycontainer" style=" ">
    <h1>System maintenance</h1>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; width=100%">
    <div style="color: #909090; background-color: black; padding: 8px; padding-left:50px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 9pt;" class="bodycontainerhf"> 
    </script></strong> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For the coding part, i'm just doing as below:

xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("./Request/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
What I'm doing is just loading the xml file.

Comment: could u plz show the xml file and the code that gives you above error?

Comment: your xml contains above html content right? so could u plz show your xml file?

Comment: Your partial xml does us no good with all the errors after you removed proprietary info.  Find an on-line xml checker.  You can validate you xml in VS using menu : Project : Add new Item : Xml File.  Then past xml into view.  The errors will show up iin the Error List like any compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply, i already took out the sensitive content and edited as above. I am able to do xmlDoc.Load if i delete the html portion manually, but i hope to do it using program.

Comment: So do it in code. Read the file line by line (there are lots of existing questions here about doing so in C#), writing each line to another file (also in many posts here), until you reach the `DOCTYPE` statement. At that point, stop. You now have the XML in its own file, where you can do whatever you want to do with it. Better yet, contact whoever is giving you the XML file and get them to fix it so it has the proper content without the HTML.

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks again for you reply.